# Cordova build command fails from command Prompt. Task 'cdvBuildDebug' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am trying to build and generate APK using command prompt. When I used command "cordova build android" for building the project, I am stuck at following issue:

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Phonegap\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'cdvBuildDebug' not found in root project 'android'.
  BUILD FAILED

Total time: 36.254 secs

- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Task 'cdvBuildDebug' not found in root project 'android'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

**Can anyone tell me where is this property "cdvBuildDebug" resides and how can i fix this issue?**

Comment: run `cordova build android --stacktrace` which will show you the exact cause/exception because of which your build is failing. Update the question with the correct cause. That will help us in helping you

Answer (score -1):

> Try to make build using the phonegap build website .
>   https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_in